# How to enqueue script and style only on single and archive page of custom post type?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a custom post type called `Movies` with `single-movies.php` and `archive-movies.php`. How can I enqueue a CSS and scripts for those pages only?

```
if ( is_single('Custom Post Type') ) {
 // Enqueue  scripts and Styles
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have custom PHP files already, why not just enqueue the scripts directly in those files?

**File Contents**:

```
<?php
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_movie_scripts' );
    function enqueue_movie_scripts(){
        wp_enqueue_style( 'my-movie-style', /* src to .css file */ );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'my-movie-script', /* src to .js file */ );
    }

    // Rest of the file here, `get_header(), content, get_footer(), etc.
 ?>
```

Or if you'd rather enqueue them from your `functions.php` or plugin file instead, you can make use of the [`is_singular()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_singular/) and [`is_post_type_archive()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_post_type_archive/) functions.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'so_50916971_enqueue_scripts' );
function so_50916971_enqueue_scripts(){
    if( is_singular( 'movies' ) || is_post_type_archive( 'movies' ) ){
        wp_enqueue_style( 'my-movie-style', /* src to .css file */ );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'my-movie-script', /* src to .js file */ );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Xhynk but I was hoping to keep this in my plugin file only

Comment: I actually just added an update to the answer that included that when I noticed the `theming` tag haha. You can make use of a simple `is_singular()` and `is_post_type_archive()` check in your enqueueing function